# Ansible to get the dict like values from a file to the playbook or loop

Tags: json, ansible, yaml

I am looking for a way to get the value from a text, yaml or json file while going through loop.

My code is working as i'm Iterating over a list of hashes with `loop` but the problem is when i'll have multiple entries to be Iterate over that's why i want to place all these values into a file and then call them in the task/playbook rather than writing bunch of line into the play.

Please suggest or help to get it through..

**Below is the working code:**

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    config: "{{ playbook_dir }}/{{ config_file }}"
    contents: "{{lookup('file', config)}}"
    server_profile_template: 'Test_apc_SY 480 Gen10 2 NVMe Application Template 20190601 V1.0'
    server_hardware: "SY 480 Gen9 1"
    template_name: []
    server_list: []

  tasks:
    - name: Create server profile
      oneview_server_profile:
        config: "{{ config }}"
        data:
          serverProfileTemplateName: "{{ server_profile_template }}"
          serverHardwareName: "{{ item.Bay }}"
          name: "{{ item.Profilename }}"
        params:
          force: True
      loop:
        - { Bay: "ENT0005, bay 11", Profilename: "test_profile01" }
        - { Bay: "ENT0005, bay 12", Profilename: "test_profile02" }

      delegate_to: localhost
      register: result

    - debug: msg= "{{ result }}"
    - debug: msg= "{{ result.msg }}"

...
```

**What is intended:**

```
$ cat bayfile.yml
---

-  'Bay: "ENT0005, bay 11", Profilename: "test_profile01"'
-  'Bay: "ENT0005, bay 12", Profilename: "test_profile02"'

...
```

**What i tried:**

```
loop: "{{ lookup('file', '{{ bayfile.yml }}') }}"
```

But above not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're headed in the right direction, but there are a couple of issues:

### Bad YAML syntax in your datafile.

In your example, you show:

```
-  'Bay: "ENT0005, bay 11", Profilename: "test_profile01"'
-  'Bay: "ENT0005, bay 12", Profilename: "test_profile02"'
```

That's a list of strings (because you have each list item enclosed in single quotes). If you want to reproduce the data you've shown in your playbook, you want a list of dictionaries. You probably want this instead:

```
- Bay: "ENT0005, bay 11"
  Profilename: "test_profile01"

- Bay: "ENT0005, bay 12"
  Profilename: "test_profile02"
```

The following is identical, just using a slightly different syntax:

```
- {Bay: "ENT0005, bay 11", Profilename: "test_profile01"}
- {Bay: "ENT0005, bay 12", Profilename: "test_profile02"}
```

### Nested jinja2 template markers

You never nest `{{...}}` markers; you only need the outermost set...everything inside is already in a Jinja template context.  Rather than:

```
loop: "{{ lookup('file', '{{ bayfile.yml }}') }}"
```

You would write:

```
loop: "{{ lookup('file', 'bayfile.yml') }}"
```

### Convert data to YAML

Lastly, when you use a `file` lookup like that, the result is simply a string (the contents of the file). You want to de-serialize that into Ansible data structures, so you'll need the `from_yaml` filter:

```
loop: "{{ lookup('file', 'bayfile.yml')  | from_yaml }}"
```

Putting that all together, we get something like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Create server profile
      debug:
        msg:
          - "{{ item.Bay }}"
          - "{{ item.Profilename }}"
      loop: "{{ lookup('file', 'bayfile.yml') | from_yaml }}"
```

## Using include_vars

Note that instead of using the `file` lookup and the `from_yaml` filter, you could use an `include_vars` task in your playbook. You would first need to reformat your datafile so that it's a dictionary instead of a list, like this:

```
oneview_servers:
  - Bay: "ENT0005, bay 11"
    Profilename: "test_profile01"

  - Bay: "ENT0005, bay 12"
    Profilename: "test_profile02"
```

And then you could write your playbook like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Read data
      include_vars:
        file: bayfile.yml
        name: data

    - name: Create server profile
      debug:
        msg:
          - "{{ item.Bay }}"
          - "{{ item.Profilename }}"
      loop: "{{ data.oneview_servers }}"
```

Comment: Nice solution @larsks, +1, i was writing the first solution but by then you summed up nicely!

Comment: thanks you larsks, lot learned from you +1, is there a way to pick these values from a simple text file.

Comment: What do you mean by "pick these values from a simple text file"?

Comment: I mean rather thank from `bayfile.yml` , like `bayfile.text`, may be i'm asking stupid question.

Comment: Sure, it's possible. You probably want to open a new question that shows the contents of the file you're trying to parse (and show how you've tried to solve it so far).